# Mysql Subquery Outer Where

Tags: mysql, subquery

Im trying to write a mysql query that will find the value to insert via a sub query and only insert into the row that has the id that is specified mysql is giving me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE product_id = '1'' at line 8
```

But i don now know what the synax should be any help is appreciated bellow is my current query.

Lewis

```
INSERT INTO oc_product 
        (tax_class_id)
        (
            SELECT tax_class_id 
            FROM oc_tax_class 
            WHERE title = 'Taxable Goods' 
        )
        WHERE product_id = '1'
```

EDIT: im a moron and i should have been using  UPDATE not insert its fixed now.

Comment: where is applied for existing records not for creating new records, and  i guess you need the where filter in inner select query or may be you need update instead of insert

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Your right im being a moron swaped it UPDATE and it works thanks :)

Comment: You can use INSERT sometimes in situations like this. You can use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. This is useful in you want to insert a record if none exists but update it if it does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you or looking to insert a new row with `product id = 1`:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product (product_id, tax_class_id)
SELECT 1, tax_class_id 
FROM oc_tax_class 
WHERE title = 'Taxable Goods'
```

Comment: It was the other way round i meant to be UPDATE but im tired thanks for your input tho.